# less psql, more emacs

Tags: emacsclient, terminal-emacs, sql

I was listening to this song today - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ajy71xw351E
Don't Wanna Leave You Now

and I realized how much I don't want to leave emacs.

I often do this after backgrounding (C-z) emacs,

psql datababase_name

> select id from table1;
>
> update table set foo="baa" where id=n;

I also often open up a gui sql browser (such as Navicat) and
order tables by a column. I might also do LIMIT to speed up query time.
Sometimes, I delete rows in a table by pressing x in the gui browser.

With Navicat, I like double clicking on a cell to edit a Postgres row
in-place.

I know I will never fully replace Navicat, but how can I use emacs
to do basic (Postgres) database work?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Emacs has in-built support for many databases, including Postgres.

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `sql-postgres` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Answer (score 7):

In addition to offby1's answer (which is what you were asking for) also take note of:

- https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CategorySql which covers `sql-mode` and `sql-interactive-mode` in general.
- https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SqlQueryBuffer which has some tips on linking a `sql-mode` buffer to a `sql-interactive-mode` buffer (which is the super-useful feature it hadn't even occurred to you to ask for).
- https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PostgreSQL which covers various *different* interfaces and items specific to postgres, which wasn't what you were asking for, but may be of interest regardless.